# Robust sandwich standard errors for weighted ordinal logistic regression

Tags: r, ordered-logit, robust-standard-error

Does anyone know if there's an implementation of ordinal logistic regression that takes weights and produces robust standard errors? This would be for IPW (otherwise I will fall back on bootstrapping!) in R.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: How to separate either ordered logit or ordered probit model is better in hausman test. Please briefly explain .thank you so much

Comment: I'm not looking to include random effects. I don't have a strong reason for choosing logit or probit. Thanks.